# How to add custom URLs to sitemap in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, sitemaps

I need to add the custom links to `sitemap.xml` in Magento 2. How can I do this?

Comment: what Magento version are you using?

Answer (score 6):

Update:

Yes, you can do that by creating plug on class `Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap`.

Create  after plugin of `collectSitemapItems()` and add your custom URL to the collection.

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type  name="Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap">
       <plugin name="add_new_item" sortOrder="1"  disabled="false"
       type="{VendorName}\{Modulename}\Plugin\Model\SitemapPlugin"/>
    </type>    
</config>
```

**Plugin class:**

```
namespace {VendorName}\{Modulename}\Plugin\Model;

class SitemapPlugin
{
       public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sitemap\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
}
public function afterCollectSitemapItems(
    \Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap $subject
    )
{


    $storeId = $subject->getStoreId();
    $newRecords = [];
    $object = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
    $object->setId(['my_uniqukey_id']);
    $object->setUrl('contact-us');
    $object->setUpdatedAt('2018-04-04 13:41:58');

    $newRecords['my_uniqukey_id'] = $object;

    $subject->addSitemapItem(new  \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        [

            'changefreq' => $this->helper->getPageChangefreq($storeId),
            'priority' => $this->helper->getPagePriority($storeId),
            'collection' => $newRecords,
        ]
     ));
}
}
```

Comment: Function is not working

Comment: which function is not working?

Comment: public function afterCollectSitemapItems(
        \Magento\Sitemap\Model\Index\Sitemap $subject, $result
    )

Comment: I have created plugin and used this code in plugin class but it is not working

Comment: it is fixed now.Pleas  check it

Comment: I have used same code, but custom link is not appering in sitemap.xml

Comment: But is working for me

Comment: @AmitBera In magento version 2.1.8, No any function available with name "collectSitemapItems".

Comment: Yes @BhaviniFlair is correct.In Magento2.1.8,  "function _initSitemapItems()" have the code which is in "collectSitemapItems".
Any other way to do this?

Comment: @Vinodkumar See my answer

Comment: @AmitBera Nice one! one question how can I add `<image:image>
<image:loc>` ?

Comment: this code in not working

Comment: @DivyeshRana how did you test it? you said its not working how did you test it

Comment: what is my_uniqukey_id

Comment: The helper in your code is now deprecated. I think you should use `\Magento\Sitemap\Model\ItemProvider\CmsPageConfigReader` now

Comment: thanks. I will look in few day

Comment: @AmitBera  I had this working on 2.2.2, installed on 2.3.4 and not firing any ideas?

Comment: 'changefreq' => 'weekly' is not showing in xml after generated xml

Comment: i had try with m240 but not display into sitemap

Answer (score 3):

Use **`\Magento\Sitemap\Model\ItemProvider`** for that you can see

**https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-create-sitemap-in-magento.html**

Comment: Work for m2.4 versions

Answer (score 1):

etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Sitemap" />
```

Model/Sitemap.php

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model;

class Sitemap extends \Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap
{
    protected function _initSitemapItems()
    {
        parent::_initSitemapItems();

        $newLine = [];
        $object = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $object->setId(['contact']);
        $object->setUrl('contact');
        $object->setUpdatedAt(date("Y-m-d h:i:s"));
        $newLine['contact'] = $object;

        $this->_sitemapItems[] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'changefreq' => 'weekly',
                'priority' => '0.25',
                'collection' => $newLine
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried the preference, and I generated the new sitemap URL, but it's not adding to the sitemap.

Comment: this code not working.

Comment: 'changefreq' => 'weekly' is not showing in xml after generated xml

Comment: Don't add a di preference for this.. Imagine you have multiple modules that would like to add something to the sitemap. Only one of those modules will have added sitemaps items.

Comment: @senthil I have also try but not adding custom post data to sitemap.xml 
which solution you have applied ?

Answer (score 0):

`addSitemapItem` is deprecated. Use `Magento\Sitemap\Model\ItemProvider` as per the latest coding standard.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sitemap\Model\ItemProvider\Composite">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="itemProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="addNewPageUrl" xsi:type="object">
                    Vendor\Module\Model\Sitemap\ItemProvider\MembershipPage
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Model\Sitemap\ItemProvider\MembershipPage

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Sitemap\ItemProvider;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;
use Magento\Sitemap\Model\ItemProvider\ItemProviderInterface;
use Magento\Sitemap\Model\ItemProvider\StoreUrlConfigReader;
use Magento\Sitemap\Model\SitemapItemFactory;

class MembershipPage implements ItemProviderInterface
{

    /**
     * @var SitemapItemFactory
     */
    private $itemFactory;

    /**
     * @var StoreUrlConfigReader
     */
    private $storeUrlConfigReader;

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $sitemapItems = [];

    /**
     * MembershipPage constructor.
     * @param SitemapItemFactory $itemFactory
     * @param StoreUrlConfigReader $storeUrlConfigReader
     * @param DateTime $date
     */
    public function __construct(
        SitemapItemFactory $itemFactory,
        StoreUrlConfigReader $storeUrlConfigReader,
        DateTime $date
    ) {
        $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
        $this->storeUrlConfigReader = $storeUrlConfigReader;
        $this->date = $date;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $storeId
     * @return array
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getItems($storeId)
    {
        $this->sitemapItems[] = $this->itemFactory->create(
            [
                'url' => 'custom-page-url',
                'updatedAt' => $this->date->date(),
                'priority' => $this->storeUrlConfigReader->getPriority($storeId),
                'changeFrequency' => $this->storeUrlConfigReader->getChangeFrequency($storeId)
            ]
        );
        return $this->sitemapItems;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

update etc/di.xml file.

```
<preference for="Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap" type="{{vendor}}\{{modulename}}\Model\Sitemap"/>
```

create Sitemap.php file in app/code/{vendor}/{modulename}/Model/

```
namespace {vendor}\{modulename}\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
class Sitemap extends \Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap
{
   public function getCustomurlCollection()
   {
    $siteMapcollection = array();
    /* if want to add multiple url then load your custom collection and set  */

       /*foreach ($siteMapcollection as $custom) { */

                $siteMapcollection[] = new DataObject([
                    'id'         => "my_custom_id",
                    'url'        => "my_custom_url",
                    'updated_at' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
                ]);
         /*     } */
        return $siteMapcollection;

   }

   public function _initSitemapItems()
    {
        $this->_sitemapItems[] = new DataObject([
            'collection' => $this->getCustomurlCollection(),
        ]);

        parent::_initSitemapItems(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: what will be the id?
url is the custom new urls right?

Comment: yes, Ex home page is not included in sitemap so if you want to add it then just add above code and add my_custom_id = "homepage" and url =  "{{your url}}"

Comment: how to check store id

Comment: protected $_storeManager;    
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    /**
     * Get store identifier
     *
     * @return  int
     */
    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    }

Comment: Don't add a di preference for this.. Imagine you have multiple modules that would like to add something to the sitemap. Only one of those modules will have added sitemaps items.