# How to add brand page URLs in sitemap.xml

Tags: catalog, magento-2.1.8, sitemaps

I have created sitemap.xml on the website. That's fine.

But I want to show brands page URLs in the sitemap.xml

How can do this?

Comment: Please see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221321/how-to-add-custom-urls-to-sitemap-in-magento-2

Comment: @BhaviniFlair, It is not working.

Comment: @VinodKumar, did you found the solution

Comment: @Jaisa, currently I don't have the code but it was worked with the help of this solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/224549/44608